# Spark RDD.pipe run bash script as a specific user

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, rdd

I notice that RDD.pipe(Seq("/tmp/test.sh")) runs the shell script with the user yarn . that is problematic because it allows the spark user to access files that    should only be accessible to the yarn user.

What is the best way to address this ?
Calling sudo -u sparkuser is not a clean solution . I would hate to even consider that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the fault of Spark to treat the Pipe() differently, but I opened a similar issue on JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/SPARK/issues/SPARK-26101

Now on to the problem. Apparently in YARN cluster Spark Pipe() asks for a container, whether your Hadoop is nonsecure or is secured by Kerberos is the difference between whether container runs by user `yarn/nobody` or the user who launches the container `your actual user`.

Either use Kerberos to secure your Hadoop or if you don't want to go through securing your Hadoop, you can set two configs in YARN which uses the Linux users/groups to launches the container. **Note**, you must **share** the same **users/groups** across all the nodes in your cluster. Otherwise, this won't work. (perhaps use LDAP/AD to sync your users/groups)

Set these:

```
yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.nonsecure-mode.limit-users = false

yarn.nodemanager.container-executor.class = org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor
```

Source: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.4/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/NodeManagerCgroups.html 
(this is the same even in Hadoop 3.0)

This fixed worked on Cloudera latest CDH 5.15.1 (yarn-site.xml):
http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-Processing-and-Workflow/YARN-force-nobody-user-on-all-jobs-and-so-they-fail/m-p/82572/highlight/true#M3882

Example:

```
val test = sc.parallelize(Seq("test user")).repartition(1)

val piped = test.pipe(Seq("whoami"))

val c = piped.collect()

est: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[4] at repartition at <console>:25
piped: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = PipedRDD[5] at pipe at <console>:25
c: Array[String] = Array(maziyar)
```

This will return the `username` who started the Spark session after setting those configs in `yarn-site.xml` and sync all the users/groups among all the nodes.